# how to combine string and number in if statement

Tags: jquery

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
    for (var j = 5; j <= 16; j++) {

        if ("tp'+i+'" == "tp'+j+'" && "lft'+i+'" == "lft'+j+'") {

            if ('k' + j == 0) {
                 "tp'+j+'" = $('#circle' + j).css("top"); "lft'+j+'" = $('#circle' + j).css("left");
                document.getElementById('circle' + j).style.left = 'lft' + j + "px";
                document.getElementById('circle' + j).style.top = 'tp' + j + "px"
            }
        }

    }"k'+i+'" = 0;
}
```

Here is the code that I am using to combine string and number in if statement, but its not happening, can anyone tell me whats wrong and how to do this?

Comment: Correct you in what? You haven't provided any problem description or expected results for what this code should do. Please update question after reading [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you have to convert num to String:

For example:

```
if (("tp" + i.toString()  == "tp"+ j.toString())  && ("lft" + i.toString() == "lft" + j.toString()))
```

Comment: yes you are right ,but after combining string and number,it is not comparing value of that variable like tp1==tp2 ,it is taking just as string and gives false

Comment: in this case use an array @user3847550